# How to prevent duplicated fetch request when making a get request call to mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, axios

I encountered a problem. I made a get request and am getting the result multiple times.
and I have removed strictmode from my indexjs.
`below is the API call`

````
        const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
        if (token !== null) {
            try {
                const chat = await axios.get('http://localhost:5500/api/chat', {
                    headers: {
                        "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`
                    }
                })
                console.log(chat.data.fetchChat);
                setFetchChat(chat.data.fetchChat)
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        }else{
            navigate('/login')
        }
    }
    useEffect(()=>{
        allChat()
    },[])```

My indexJs file

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';
import './index.css'


const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));

root.render( <App />)
````

Comment: You're missing essential code to make this question complete/ "answerable". Probably you're component is re-rendering and you're firing a request on every re-render?